# SQL full-text index on a VIEW locking the main TABLE

Tags: sql, text, indexing

I have an interesting (read frustrating) problem with running a Full Text index on an SQL View.

1. In the SQL VIEW I create the unique clustered index.
2. The Full Text Index populates fine (100K records)
3. However, the main table that is used to populate the VIEW is locked from making any UPDATES while I have the Full Text Index active on the VIEW.

Once I delete or disable the Full Text index on the VIEW I am once again able to make UPDATES to the main TABLE.

Can you offer any ideas as to how I can have the Full Text Index on the view whilst being able to make updated to the main table?

Thanks,

Conan

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: Ok I've found the solution myself.

The issue was caused by SELECT permissions not being equal on both the VIEW and TABLE.

Comment: Please consider deleting the question.